# MergedDictionary behaves differently when in it's own file vs. embeded in the Window?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have multiple `ResourceDictionaries` together in a folder in my project and previously I used to use `MergedDictionaries` in my `Window.Resources` to bring them together into one dictionary. I then moved that merged dictionary to it's own file, and all of the styles and everything works exactly the same... except for the Menu control's background. Nothing has changed except the dictionary having its own file, and everything else works fine. I even have the dummy style added in there and the Menu's background still won't display. Any idea what could be wrong?

.NET version : 4

Comment: Is it the `Menu` or the popup of a `MenuItem`? Can you show us the xaml of the element that you expect to be colored? (if it's a `TemplateBinding` then add the relevant setter the style)

Comment: @XAMeLi it's the background of the popup, yes. The XAML from the ResourceDictionary or the XAML from the Window's `Menu` control?